# MySQL - Need to retrieve muliple advisor's data - select SUM seems to prevent

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

Currently using the following query:

```
select distinct(shift_report.advisor), users.team, shift_report.date
from shift_report join users on shift_report.advisor=users.username
where `date` >=20160224
and users.team=1
```

this gives me data for each advisor. I want to calculate total time spent for each however, when I add the following to the query it only returns data for one advisor, but the times etc seem to be team totals:

```
SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, round(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2)
as percentage
```

When I run the above including the SUMs for an individual the query works.

Comment: Your query lacks `group by` clause, therefore sum() collapses the output into a single record. You need to provide by which fields you want to show the sums by. My guess would be shift_report.advisor, users.team, shift_report.date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an aggregation function, you have to specify a group by clause in order to get the results for each partition(advisor in this case)

```
select shift_report.advisor, users.team, shift_report.date,
       SUM(shift_report.time) as total_time, round(SUM(shift_report.time)/450 * 100,2)
from shift_report join users on shift_report.advisor=users.username
where `date` >=20160224
and users.team=1
GROUP BY shift_report.advisor,users.team,shift_report.date
```

I assumed you want to group by all this columns (advisor,team,date) if not, remove them from the group by clause

Comment: You can remove distinct and put it in the GROUP BY,since it`s not a function

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly, exactly what I needed.

Comment: No problem :) @GrahamDrummond